# Pass ng-template From A Component To ng-select Inside Another Component

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to pass an ng-template from my main component into an ng-select inside another component. How can i do so?

Already tried to use ng-content or a template reference but it is still not working.

What i am trying to achieve is exactly the same as the ng-select custom template example, except that the ng-template is provided from another component. So intead of this:

```
<ng-select [items]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        <img height="15" width="15" [src]="item.avatar"/>
        {{item.name}}
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

**select-custom.component.html**

```
<ng-select [items]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
    <ng-content></ng-content> --> this is not working, templateref also not working
</ng-select>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-select-custom>
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        <img height="15" width="15" [src]="item.avatar"/>
        {{item.name}}
    </ng-template>
</app-select-custom>
```

Comment: not sure if the TemplateRef i'm working on is correct. If it is possible with TemplateRef could someone help with example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-43wmxu?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question. Thanks to @yurzui:

[stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-43wmxu?file=app/app.component.ts](http://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-43wmxu?file=app/app.component.ts)

**ContentChild in custom-select.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-select',
  templateUrl: './custom-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-select.component.css']
})
export class CustomSelectComponent  {
   @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>
   cities = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Vilnius', avatar: 'https://avatars.io/platform/userId'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Kaunas', avatar: 'https://avatars.io/platform/userId'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Pavilnys', disabled: true, avatar: 'https://avatars.io/platform/userId'},
        {id: 4, name: 'Pabradė', avatar: 'https://avatars.io/platform/userId'},
        {id: 5, name: 'Klaipėda', avatar: 'https://avatars.io/platform/userId'}
    ];

}
```

**custom-select.component.html**

```
<ng-select [items]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" bindLabel="name" bindValue="name">
  <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{item: item}"></ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-custom-select>
    <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
        <img height="15" width="15" [src]="item.avatar"/>
        {{item.id}}
    </ng-template>
</app-custom-select>
```